# Gradle write new pom

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

I am trying to create new pom with gradle. here is the code I use:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            inceptionYear '2015'
            distributionManagement {
                repository {
                    id 'maven'
                    name 'Maven'
                    url 'xxxxxxxx'
            }
                snapshotRepository {
                    id 'snapshots-maven'
                    name 'Snapshots Maven'
                    url 'xxxxxxxx'
            }
        }
    }
  }.writeTo("wpom.xml")
}
```

I have the repository closure inside the distributionManagement, it will throw the following exception:

Cannot cast object 'org.apache.maven.model.Repository@47a5ea25' with class 'org.apache.maven.model.Repository' to class 'org.apache.maven.model.DeploymentRepository'

exactly same problem was reported on gradle forum with no response:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/failed-to-write-new-pom-with-distributionmanagement-repository

Can anyone help?